# Google Analytics - For RealTime reports, how can you list all Active Users and Pageviews?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, reporting

Under Realtime reporting > Content, Google Analytics displays the number of Active Users and Pageviews in the last 30 minutes. Unfortunately, the table for each only lists up to 20 rows. Ergo, I can only see up to 20 Active Pages under Active Users, even if the total metric shows 50, for example.

How can I expand the number of rows? Is pagination available? I've been poking around Admin settings and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the entire data that the report does not show you, programmatically by querying the View via the Real Time API.